# Using laravel and trying to call a public function and recieving the error message - 'Undefined method 'photos'.intelephense(1013) '

Tags: php, laravel, model, controller, undefined

Sorry for bad formatting i am new to this - I am trying to make a manage user photos page with laravel, i am doing this by forming a relationship through public functions in the App/Models files and then linking them to a controller. After making the function 'photo()' within the users model and then writing the necessary code in the 'PhotoController' - i am giving the error code 'Undefined method 'photos'.intelephense(1013) '

I cant seem to figure out why i keep getting this error message and would be very thankful if someone understood why this is happening!

i tried calling 'App/Model/User' within the PhotoController but to no avail.

PhotoController code -

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Photos;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
use Barryvdh\Debugbar\Facades\Debugbar;

class PhotoController extends Controller
{
    //show all photos
    public function index() {
        DebugBar::info('Showing the Message!');
        return view('listpg', [
            'photos' => Photos::latest()->filter(request(['tag', 'search']))->paginate(6)
        ]);
    }

    //show single photo
    public function show(Photos $photo) {
        return view('photo', [
            'photo' => $photo
        ]);
    }

    //creation form
    public function create() {
        return view('create');
    }

    //store photo
    public function store(Request $request) {
        $formFields = $request->validate([
            'title' => 'required',
            'name' => ['required',Rule::unique('photos', 'name')],
            'tags' => 'required',
            'body' => 'required'
        ]);

        if($request->hasFile('image_path')) {
            $formFields['image_path'] = $request->file('image_path')->store('images', 'public');
        }

        $formFields['user_id'] = auth()->id();

        Photos::create($formFields);


        return redirect('/')->with('message', 'Post created successfully!');
    }

    //Edit form
    public function edit(Photos $photo) {
        return view('edit', ['photo' => $photo]);
    }

     //update photo
     public function update(Request $request, Photos $photo) {
        $formFields = $request->validate([
            'title' => 'required',
            'name' => ['required'],
            'tags' => 'required',
            'body' => 'required'
        ]);

        if($request->hasFile('image_path')) {
            $formFields['image_path'] = $request->file('image_path')->store('images', 'public');
        }


        $photo->update($formFields);


        return back()->with('message', 'Post updated successfully!');
    }

    //Delete Listing
    public function destroy(Photos $photo){
        $photo->delete();
        return redirect('/')->with('message', 'Post deleted successfully!');
    }

    //Manage posts
    public function manage() {
        return view('manage', ['photos' => auth()->user()->photos()->get()]);
    }
}
```

User.php - user model -

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array<string, string>
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    //relation with posts
    public function photos() {
        return $this->hasMany(Photos::class, 'user_id');
    }
}
```

Photos.php - Photos model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Photos extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    //protected $fillable = ['title', 'name', 'tags', 'body'];

    public function scopeFilter($query, array $filters) {
        if($filters['tag'] ?? false) {
            $query->where('tags', 'like', '%' . request('tag'). '%');
        }

        if($filters['search'] ?? false) {
            $query->where('title', 'like', '%' . request('search'). '%')
                ->orWhere('body', 'like', '%' . request('search'). '%')
                ->orWhere('tags', 'like', '%' . request('search'). '%');
        }
    }

    //relationship to user
    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
    }

}
```

Comment: I think you are using `VSCode`, do not worry, the issue is just that the _intelephense_ is not smart enough to understand that `auth()->user()` returns `User` (`User` has `photos` method), so just ignore it. I will not be able to help you solve the issue as I do not use VSCode, I do use PHPStorm with [`barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper`](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper), that one works on PHPStorm only (it does correctly understand this relation that is not working for you and more things)

Comment: ^ Was just about to post this too; VSCode has issues detecting what `auth()->user()` equates to, but it returns a single `User` instance, which does have a `photos()` method as defined by you. Quick sidenote, Models are Singular, so you should call it `Photo.php`, and `class Photo extends Model { ... }`.

Comment: Thank you very much - so basically dont worry about i then and it should still pass through fine?

Comment: Yup; unless your code actually triggers an error when you try to access the Route associated with your `manage()` method, then this is a "red herring"; something that seems like an issue but really isn't. And that `laravel-ide-helper` Package can be used in VSCode too, but I'm not sure if it fixes this specific problem. Using newer versions of PHP/Laravel could help too, if that's an option 